# Selenium Grid Remote Third party proxy not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid, http-proxy, selenium-hub

Currently using the selenium hub and node configuration and using the Python test connecting to hub using 4444. When I provide the proxy, the requests are not routing it through.

Using below stack:
Python 3
Selenium 4.X

k8 yaml for hub

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: selenium-hub
  labels:
    app: selenium-hub
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: selenium-hub
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: selenium-hub
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: selenium-hub
          image: selenium/hub:4.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4444
            - containerPort: 4443
            - containerPort: 4442
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "4096Mi"
              cpu: "4"
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /wd/hub/status
              port: 4444
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /wd/hub/status
              port: 4444
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 5
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: selenium-hub
  labels:
    app: selenium-hub
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 4444
      targetPort: 4444
      name: port0
    - port: 4443
      targetPort: 4443
      name: port1
    - port: 4442
      targetPort: 4442
      name: port2
  selector:
    app: selenium-hub
  type: NodePort
  sessionAffinity: None
```

K8 Yaml for node

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: selenium-node-chrome
  labels:
    app: selenium-node-chrome
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: selenium-node-chrome
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: selenium-node-chrome
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: dshm
          emptyDir:
            medium: Memory
      containers:
        - name: selenium-node-chrome
          image: selenium/node-chrome:4.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5555
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /dev/shm
              name: dshm
          env:
            - name: SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST
              value: "selenium-hub"
            - name: SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT
              value: "4443"
            - name: SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT
              value: "4442"
            - name: SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS
              value: "8"
            - name: SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS
              value: "true"
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "4096Mi"
              cpu: "4"
```

Python code to connect to the server:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=chrome')
    proxy2 = webdriver.Proxy()
    proxy2.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
    proxy2.http_proxy = PRX
    proxy2.httpProxy = PRX
    proxy2.ssl_proxy = PRX
    proxy2.sslProxy = PRX
    proxy2.no_proxy = ""
    chrome_options.proxy = proxy2
driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", options=chrome_options, 
    )
```

Tried this one as well

```
manifest_json = """
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}
"""

background_js = """
var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
        singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "%s",
            port: parseInt(%s)
        },
        bypassList: ["localhost"]
        }
    };

chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "%s",
            password: "%s"
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
            callbackFn,
            {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
            ['blocking']
);
""" % (
    PROXY_HOST,
    PROXY_PORT,
    PROXY_USER,
    PROXY_PASS,
)

pluginfile = "proxy_auth_plugin.zip"

        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, "w") as zp:
            zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
            zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
        chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
```

I observed the proxy logs and no logs present this could be the indication.